# iOS Tableview. Custom cell always has a content view of 320 width and 44 height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

So I am programmatically setting the `frame` and settings of a `UITableView` in my `UIViewController`, and then using a custom `UITableViewCell` to populate it with data. The problem is that the custom cell **ALWAYAS** has a `frame` and `contentView` of **320** width and **44** `height` even if I set it with `initWithFrame`.

**My code:**

Table creation:

```
UITableView *pickPlayerNameTable = 
  [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 
                                                15,  
                                                (viewSize.width - 20), 
                                                4 * (viewSize.height/5) - 15)];

pickPlayerNameTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
pickPlayerNameTable.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
// playerNameTable.

[self.view addSubview:pickPlayerNameTable];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:pickPlayerNameTable];

//set the controller as the tables delegate and data source
pickPlayerNameTable.delegate = self;
pickPlayerNameTable.dataSource = self;
```

**The cellRowForIndexpath method:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *cellIdentifier = @"playerNameSellectionCell";

PlayerNameCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


if(cell==nil)
{
    cell = [[PlayerNameCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

//set the label to the corresponding player
cell.playerNumberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Παίκτης %ld:", (indexPath.row + 1)];

return cell;
}
```

**And last the custom cell, `initWithStlye` method:**

```
//override initWithStyle for custom cell
-(id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

//if initialized successfully, create ui
if(self)
{
    //get the cell's frame size
    CGSize cellSize = self.contentView.frame.size;
    //CGSize viewSize = self.frame.size;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    //set up the player number label
    self.playerNumberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8.0, 4.0, (cellSize.width/2 - 16), (cellSize.height - 8))];
    [self.playerNumberLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Aka-AcidGR-ScrachThis" size:30]];
    [self.playerNumberLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.playerNumberLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    [self.playerNumberLabel setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

    //add label to cell
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.playerNumberLabel];

    //set up the textfield for the cell
    self.playerNameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( cellSize.width/2, 4.0, (cellSize.width/2 - 8), (cellSize.height - 8))];
    [self.playerNameTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.playerNameTextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];

    [self.contentView addSubview:self.playerNameTextField];

}

return self;
}
```

And an image of the current end result:

[image: Current cell Result]

As you can see the textfield doesn't start from either the middle part, nor is it half in width, and that's because is always has a width of 320, even if the tableview is smaller than that (case when running on iphone 5) or larger (iphone 6).

Any help please? Thank you.

Comment: Did you set **rowHeight** of UITableViewCell? if you did show us how you did?

Comment: You have to use the `delegate` of your `UITableView` --> `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: My issue is not the height though, it's the width

Answer (score 1):

You can use the delegate method to set the height:

```
// For swift:
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat

// For Objective-C
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Antoine's answer is true, but if your issue about **CustomCell's** subviews you need to layout subviews. According to [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews)

> layoutSubviews - Implement this method if you need more precise control over the layout of your subviews than either the constraint or autoresizing behaviors provide.

so you need to implement `- (void)layoutSubviews` method in your **UITableViewCell**

You should also implement

```
  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

if you don't, your cell height always become default value.

Comment: this seems usefull, I'll check it out later and let you know. thanks :)